# JPA use IN clause with objects

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I am facing a problem usign JPA, and more specifically using a IN clause.

The best way is, I think, to show you my code :

```java
@NamedQuery(name = "Commande.findCustom", query = "SELECT DISTINCT [myFields] "
            + "FROM Commande c WHERE "
            + "[SomeCriterias] AND "
            + "c.ID IN (SELECT t.ID FROM SubTable t "
            + "WHERE t.IDX IN :param) AND [otherCriterias]"),
```

I then get an error from MySQL :

```sql
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.ID FROM SubTable t1 WHERE (t1.IDX IN (168)'
```

I am looking for a response but can't find anything ...

I tied to delete a IN clause, the problem is still the same (so it's not a double IN use problem)

my `:param` is a List of objects, that i got by using the `Object.find()` method. As you can see, it returns the ID (168). But I can't seem to find the problem ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

**EDIT : Full query**

```java
@NamedQuery(name = "Commande.findCustom", query = "SELECT DISTINCT c.idChargement, c.libelle, "
            + "c.codeTransporteur, c.reference, c.dateCreation, c.dateChargementPrevu, "
            + "c.dateValidationChargement, c.dateLivraisonPrevue, c.codeDestinataire, "
            + "c.raisonSocialeDestinataire, c.adresseDestinataire, c.codePostalDestinataire, "
            + "c.villeDestinataire, c.paysDestinataire, c.contactDestinataire, "
            + "c.telephoneDestinataire, c.mailDestinataire, c.poidsCommande, c.nombreColis, "
            + "c.nombreUniteManutention, c.typeUniteManutention, c.prendreRDV, c.commentaires "
            + "FROM Commande c WHERE "
            + "c.idChargement = :idChargement AND c.codeTransporteur = :codeTransporteur AND "
            + "(c.dateCreation BETWEEN :dateDebut AND :dateFin) AND "
            + "c.idDernierStatut IN (SELECT l.idListeStatutsCommande FROM Listestatutscommande l "
            + "WHERE l.idStatut IN :idStatut) AND c.raisonSocialeDestinataire = :raisonSociale AND "
            + "c.adresseDestinataire = :adresseDestinataire AND c.codeDestinataire = :codeDestinataire "
            + "AND c.codePostalDestinataire = :codePostal AND c.villeDestinataire = :villeDestinataire "
            + "AND c.paysDestinataire = :codePays")
```

And the Error Message

```sql
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.idListeStatutsCommande FROM listestatutscommande t1 WHERE (t1.IdStatut IN (168)'
```

Comment: are you running it with implementation as hibernate?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar No I'm not, I checked the problem with the parenthesis, it's not that too ...

Comment: I would say that something is wrong with `.ID` not with `IN`clause

Comment: @Antoniossss I agree, but then what ? As you cann see in the error, the IDs are there

Comment: I have just tested response message of MYSQL, and in case of error "near" is beginning at the point of error. Don't know what is wrong tough.

Comment: could you please post full query that you are executing? It seems you have kept placeholder in the question instead of real query

Comment: @Antoniossss oh, that's very helpful, I am going to investigate on that, thank you

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Done, see the edit in the post

Comment: @trichetriche also update your error message to correspond to the full query.

Comment: is there any possibility that `idListeStatutsCommande` is misstyped?

Comment: @Antoniossss I'm sorry, here you go. And no, I copy them directly from the class

Comment: @Antoniossss as you said earlier, I think it should throw a jpql error message if it was misspelled and not sql error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the problem, and then the answer. Thanks @Antoniossss, the fact is that I was looking at the wrong part of the query.

The error was here : `c.idDernierStatut IN ...`

The fact is that this part is a foreign key. And when you want to search on it, you have to consider it as an object. So the correct form is `c.idDernierStatut.idListeStatutsCommande IN` to get the ID.

Thank you to both of you for your time anyway !

Comment: good that you could solve. It is called a path expression. in JPQL, we are dealing with objects and not with database tables, thats why you'll have to traverse using object properties. Happy learning.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I'm in fact learning it, that's an useful piece of advice. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting error from `MYSQL` not `Hibernate`, you could try to find out what query actually is generated. To do this, use proxy invoker like `p6spy` and then everything should be clear. Check p6spy [site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/). When you do, try to invoke such generated SQL yourself and try to fix it. I used such method when I had some troubles using JPA's joins fetches and stuff. Very helpfull in diagnosing such problems.

Comment: even I had to follow the same approach while learning jpql. Good suggestion. Upvote from e.